# Unable to display value on UILabel upon button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display weather data values (fetched by making API call) on UILabels and here is the code:

```
self.maxTempField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",vari[@"main"][@"\"temp_max\""]];
NSLog(@"Max Temp %@", vari[@"main"][@"temp_max"]);
self.atmosphericPresField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"main"][@"pressure"]];
self.windSpeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"wind"][@"speed"]];
NSLog(@"Speeed of the wind %@", vari[@"wind"][@"speed"]);
```

I am unable to understand why the labels are not being updated. I also tried to replace `UILabel` with `UITextField` but problem persists. Here is the complete code for button action:

```
- (IBAction)moreProperties:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *refToStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *pointerToMoreValuesVC = [refToStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MorePropertiesVC"];
    pointerToMoreValuesVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:pointerToMoreValuesVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.noteLabel.text = @"Random Text";

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.maxTempField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",vari[@"main"][@"\"temp_max\""]];
        NSLog(@"Max Temp %@", vari[@"main"][@"temp_max"]);
        self.atmosphericPresField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"main"][@"pressure"]];
        self.windSpeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"wind"][@"speed"]];
        NSLog(@"Speeed of the wind %@", vari[@"wind"][@"speed"]);
    });
}
```

I also checked all my label connections and they are good.

Comment: An `IBAction` will always run on the main thread; there is no need to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I removed the instruction for main thread and the fields still won't update.

Comment: Do the `NSLog` statements appear? Put a breakpoint on the line where you attempt to update the label. Is `self.maxTempField` non-nil? Is `self.windSpeed` non-nil?

Comment: @rmaddy The NSLog statements execute. I didn't understand if UITextFields can be non-nil..

Comment: clean your project and also remove from cache data from window=>projects  and run it again.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya Tried cleaning cache data.. Would you be interested in taking a look at the code ? Here is the Git URL for it https://github.com/abdkareem/WeatherToday.git

Comment: @Abdkar i seen your project. You find out problem or not?

Comment: I haven't found the problem yet. Could you let me know what's preventing the fields from being updated ?

Comment: Yes it is because of two same name view controller. You need to just create another class and assign your outlet to that classes.

Comment: @Abdkar solution work for you or not?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya your solution worked absolutely well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all create new class named as WetherDetailVC
2. Now you have two files .h and .m
3. Assign class WetherDetailVC to your view view controller in identity inspector
4. If you don't want to create outlet again, just cut your all outlet(maxTempField,minTempField,...etc)and paste it all in WetherDetailVC.h file
5. Now access all your outlet using class object in your ViewController.h

   ```
   - (IBAction)moreProperties:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *refToStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    WetherDetail *pointerToMoreValuesVC = [refToStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MorePropertiesVC"];
    pointerToMoreValuesVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   [self presentViewController:pointerToMoreValuesVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    pointerToMoreValuesVC.noteLabel.text = @"Random Text";
    pointerToMoreValuesVC.maxTempField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",vari[@"main"][@"temp_max"]];
    pointerToMoreValuesVC.atmosphericPressureField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"main"][@"pressure"]];
     pointerToMoreValuesVC.windSpeedField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vari[@"wind"][@"speed"]];
   }
   ```

Comment: Creating a new class for a new view controller on story board solved the whole problem. Works well. Thank you!